# Gyroscope too sensitive

Tags: android

Okay im trying to let a triangle move. Now it does work but i cant balance it in the middle. Its too sensitive. This is my code:

```
float accelx = event.values[0];
if (accelx > PreviousX2) {
    if (posx > -2) {
    Triangle.setPosX(posx - 0.1f);
    Triangle.setPosY(posy - 0.1f);
    Triangle.setPosZ(posz - 0.1f);
    }
}
if (accelx < PreviousX2) {
    if (posx < 0) {
    Triangle.setPosX(posx + 0.1f);
    Triangle.setPosY(posy + 0.1f);
    Triangle.setPosZ(posz + 0.1f);
    }
}
break;
```

It does work but i cant balance it into the middle... How to make it less sensitive so its abled to stay in the middle of the screen, because now it just stays at the right or the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deadband around a set of values for `accelx`.

For example, the following code will filter out any acceleration around the X-axis less than 1 rad/s:

```
float accelx = event.values[0];
if (accelx < 1) {
    // Value isn't significant enough, so i
    return;
} else {
    // Proceed as usual
}
```